# Android,how could i make a full app been install on the SD Card

Tags: android

I already build my app but just realize that the app its heavy so i wanted to know how could i make all my been install in the Sd Card.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
  package="com.Travel"
  android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.00B1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <activity android:name=".Travel"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html):

Modify your manifest file this way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

This will only work on devices running Android 2.2 or higher.

Comment: You do not have a closing tag for `manifest`. Put `</manifest>` at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks i check if its been install on the SD Card but i see that not,what could be wrong